# Why is my system using the secondary dns server instead of primary?

Tags: dns

I have a domain I use for applications I self-host. Let's call it example.dev. I use Cloudflare Tunnels to proxy http requests to those applications. This works great when I'm out.

When I'm home there isn't really a reason to go through Cloudflare. So I set up AdGuardHome and have a DNS override so anything hitting *.example.dev is forwarded to my homelab server.

My router/dhcp hands out `192.168.1.2` as the *Primary* (Adguard) and `192.168.1.1` as the *Secondary* (My gateway itself)

This is working perfect on all but one computer. My Ubuntu laptop (22.04.3 LTS) wants to resolve example.dev to my WAN IP.

Running `resolvectrl status` shows that I am getting the right setup, but look at the output. It wants to default to my secondary sever. Why? Is there a way I can force it?

Oh, and I can ping `192.168.1.2` from this laptop. If I reboot, it will use that DNS server for a few minutes but it switches back to .1. Can I stop that from happening?

[image]

Comment: Simply put, the OS can use any DNS server that is available. So if you don't want a particular server to be used, then don't offer it to the client. This answer will provide more info: [Stop resolvectl Changing DNS](https://askubuntu.com/a/1473388/1684306)

Comment: I thought the whole purpose was to have a primary and then a secondary as a backup when the primary is offline. Huh....Today I Learned

Comment: If you read `man resolv.conf` you will see `If there are multiple servers, the resolver  library  queries  them in the order listed.`  You can have the "primary" and "secondary" type setup as long as the first one you have listed responds fast enough.  I actually have this configured and for the most part it will hit the one I have listed first, but sometimes it gets overwhelmed and goes to the one I have listed second.  So my second one has the same stuff my first one does.